# PHP Warning: file_get_contents() in error_log

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-3.5, error-pages

I used [OSTraining](https://www.ostraining.com/)'s instructions to [Create a Custom Joomla 404 Page with 404 Status Code](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/custom-404/) in one of my J! 3.5.1 sites. However, the error_log is flooded with the following errors:

```
[09-Jun-2016 04:05:45 America/Detroit] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents({...}/404): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

Occasionally, a few other warnings pop up:

```
[08-Jun-2016 13:15:22 America/Detroit] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/{...}/public_html/templates/theme1666/error.php on line 26
[08-Jun-2016 13:15:22 America/Detroit] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents({...}http/404): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/{...}/public_html/templates/theme1666/error.php on line 26
[08-Jun-2016 13:15:22 America/Detroit] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/{...}/public_html/templates/theme1666/error.php on line 26
[08-Jun-2016 13:15:22 America/Detroit] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents({...}http/404): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/{...}/public_html/templates/theme1666/error.php on line 26
```

Here is my code showing line 26:

```
if ($this->error->getCode() == '404') : {
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  echo file_get_contents(JURI::root().'404');
  exit;
}
```

Obviously, the network errors are due to non-existent URLs. However, the question remains, why is the `JURI::root()` function randomly generating non-existent URLs? And, why am I getting 500 errors when the page seems to display correctly?

---

Note: {...} represents account or domain name.

Comment: Are you sure you're copying the alias of the article? Be sure you assign the article to a menu item too

Comment: It isn't producing random URLs.  That would produce the URL www.mydomain.com/404,  you need to have an endpoint (aka file, menu alias) that appears not to exist.

Comment: [@Lodder](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/168/lodder) & [@BrianBolli](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/1906/brian-bolli), I have ensured that there is, indeed, a published menu item with alias "404" which points to the single article, also having the alias "404".

Comment: I am still getting this error, daily. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if this will have any impact but you do not need the ":" in the if statement.

Comment: @BodgeIT, the next line is `else :` followed by some more code. ;)

Comment: I am still getting these errors once every day or so.